# Tracking downloads from html5 download attribute using Google Analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics, download

Looking for a way to track downloads of pdf files when using the new HTML5 download attribute. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this in Google Analytics. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 downloads attribute is only about the filename. It stay a normal link you can track with event as explain int the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

Do something like :

```
<a href="your_file_url.pdf" downloads="file_name" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'pdf', 'file_name']);">Download the pdf</a>
```